# Attribute Table Decimal Places 

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, attribute-table

As we all know, the attribute table field properties has number format to display number of decimal places to up to maximum 15.
If we have many fields/columns in attribute table, how can we change all fields/columns decimal places roundoff/display at a time ( I mean in single operation. Not changing each and every field properties).

Ex:

```
ColA:12.987654 ! ColB:34.20987766  ! ColC:89.654309877
```

In one operation my output should be (Rounding/display to 2 digits)

For Rounding:

```
ColA:12.99 ! ColB:34.201  ! ColC:89.66
```

For Display:

```
ColA:12.98 ! ColB:34.20  ! ColC:89.65
```

is there any method/tool to do this in Arcgis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. I don't think there's something like that. Iterating over the fields and changing the precision property is the closest you can do I guess. There's a [LisField](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ListFields/000v0000001p000000/) function so it shouldn't be so troublesome.

Comment: I am looking for this operation and may me others also looking like me. Is there any chance we can give input to arcgis to incorporate this facility?

Comment: What's wrong with an arcpy script? You can send your suggestions to the ESRI forums, I guess.

Comment: Or at ArcGIS Ideas http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaHome?c=09a300000004xET Good luck :)

Comment: Hi R.K, as you suggested, I posted on the link provided.Thank you.